# Should test cases written before or after creating the project?

Tags: java, junit

When the JUnit test cases have to be written logically? Before or after creating the application? For big applications how it should be written? Based on the code we created or based on the requirement specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally unit test cases should be written first and then the code.  Many people follow Test driven Development([TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)). But again its choice and as part of best practice  i prefer TDD.

> TDD (Test Driven Development) is a computer programming method that
>   consists of small iterations. In this method you begin by writing the
>   test cases covering the new functionality, then you write the
>   production code necessary to make the test pass, and after that you
>   refactor the code to make it more maintainable. Writing the tests
>   before writing the code guaranties immediate feedback after changes
>   are made.  TDD (test-driven development) is a technique for designing
>   the software as well as testing it.
>
> In Test Driven Development (TDD) automated unit tests are written
>   before the code is actually written. Running these tests give you fast
>   confirmation of whether your code behaves as it should

.